# Passing an enum as a parameter in a method?

Tags: java, enums, parameters

I have an abstract class Medium, where one of the datamembers is an enum.

```
private Taal talenOndertiteling[];

public enum Taal {
    NEDERLANDS, FRANS, DUITS, ENGELS, SPAANS, ITALIAANS
}
public Taal[] getTalenOndertiteling() {
    return talenOndertiteling;
}

public void setTalenOndertiteling(Taal[] talenOndertiteling) {
    this.talenOndertiteling = talenOndertiteling;
}
```

Now when I try to call the last method like this:

```
            BD bd1 = new BD();
            bd1.setTalenOndertiteling(Taal.ENGELS);
```

I'm getting an error. (The BD class implements the Medium class) Any ideas on how I should be calling the method? And what if I wanted to set several languates, how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: (Note, you almost certainly want to be cloning that array on the way in and out, or better copy a `Collection`.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cloning? And why would a collection be better? I don't see the difference between using an array or something else (ArrayList?) if I'm only using it as a parameter for the method. Thank you for mentioning this!

Comment: Not cloning means that your "private" variable is mutable from the outside. This can lead to obscure bugs (and in my line of work, expensive security vulnerabilities). Collections offer a nicer interface (apart from `[]`), rather than an exposed implementation technique. For instance, you probably (though not necessarily, I can't tell from the use of arrays) want the array to behave like a set, so `Set` would be an obvious thing to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method accepts a `Taal[]` but your invocation passes a `Taal`.  You have two choices:

Either pass an explicit `Taal[]`:

```
bd1.setTalenOndertiteling(new Taal[] {Taal.ENGELS});
```

or, change the method declaration to take a [vararg](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter and have the compiler do it for you:

```
public void setTalenOndertiteling(Taal... talenOndertiteling) {
```

Comment: I consider the most elegant way to allow one parameter use is to use vararg, which makes a far cleaner code, with no feature loss.

Comment: There's very few reasons not to.  One reason I can think of is if you intend to pass a literal `null` parameter, the method invocation is ambiguous.  That's somewhat annoying, but I agree that it's almost always a good idea.

Comment: @Riduidel - only if if makes *sense* to accept multiple parameters (you've got to write the implementation after all), when it's the obvious option anyway.  For example, on the canonical `Person` class, what would you gain from declaring `setAge(int... age)`?  What would it mean to call `setAge(11, 72, 43)`?

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle: I interpreted his comment to mean "instead of accepting an array", not to mean that **every** method should accept varargs.

Comment: Oh well, you're obviously right. But I was talking of that particular case. unfortunatly, it was not obvious enough from my sentence. However, i could be a very fun way to have the <code>setAge(int... age)</code> to have multiple events fired (in a swing application, as an example) :-)

Comment: Oh right.  Sorry, that's quite obvious in retrospect, pardon my misinterpretation.  I thought it was analogous to the proposed practice that any method that's declared as returning `void` should instead `return this` to allow method chaining.  Interesting, but possibly obscuring readability.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an array with one element and pass it to the method:

```
bd1.setTalenOndertiteling(new Taal[]{Taal.ENGELS});
```

Answer (score 0):

The setter expects an array of Taal enums.

So the proper use is:

```
BD bd1 = new BD();
bd1.setTalenOndertiteling(new Taal[]{Taal.ENGELS});
```

or more verbose:

```
BD bd1 = new BD();

Taal[] taals = new Taal[1];
taals[0] = Taal.ENGELS;

bd1.setTalenOndertiteling(taals);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setTalenOrdertiteling` gets an array.
So the correct call should be:

```
bd1.setTalenOndertiteling(new Taal[] {Taal.ENGELS});
```

Answer (score 0):

two issues:
1) setTalenOndertiteling() is expecting array of Taal, so

```
bd.setTalenOndertiteling(new Taal[]{Taal.ENGELS};
```

2) Taal seems to be a nested enum (in BD?), without specific import, you need to do

```
bd.setTalenOndertiteling(new BD.Taal[]{BD.Taal.ENGELS};
```

Comment: Actually Taal is a datamember from my Medium class. BD is only extending Medium. Thanks for answering!